# pointer conversion error c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I write a simple `list` class that part of is look like that: 
When I try to build the project the compilers shows 3 errors that one of them is with pointer conversion problems and I cant get why:

Compiler error says:

> 1. 'MyList::Node *MyList::begin(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyList' to 'MyList &'
> 2. 'MyList::Node *MyList::end(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyList' to 'MyList &'
> 3. 'MyList::create': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments

The class(only little part..)

```
template<class T>
class MyList
{   
public:

    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
    };
    typedef Node* node_iterator;


    node_iterator begin() { return first; }
    node_iterator end() { return last; }

    ...

    MyList() { create(); }//default constructor
    MyList(size_type n, const T& val = T()){create(n, val);}
    MyList(const MyList& l) { create(l.begin(), l.end()); }//copy constructor
    MyList& operator=(const MyList&);//assignment operator
    ~MyList() { uncreate(); }

private:

    node_iterator first;
    node_iterator last;
    ...
    ...

};

MyList<T> & MyList<T>::operator=(const MyList& rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        uncreate();
        create(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::create(node_iterator a, node_iterator b)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As is currently written, we cannot reproduce your problem here.

Comment: In `operator=()`, the argument `rhs` is a `const` reference.   `create(rhs.begin(), rhs.end())` attempts to call non-`const` member functions.   That is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling

```
create(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
```

Where `rhs` is a const object. But you are calling `begin` and `end` that requires the object to not be const. Either change

```
 MyList<T> & MyList<T>::operator=(const MyList& rhs)
```

to

```
 MyList<T> & MyList<T>::operator=(MyList& rhs)
```

Or make `begin` and `end` work for const objects. i.e. `node_iterator begin() const { return first; }`

Fix this then work on any other compiler errors/warnings.